# Azure AD refusing to match reply URL

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I'm trying to configure my old application to use the current .net core method of authenticating accounts based on an existing Microsoft account.

Clicking on the button does indeed send me to be authenticated and Microsoft, but when I log in, I get this error message:

> AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application:

Currently the method I'm calling when someone tries to log on via MS is:

```
public IActionResult ExternalLogin(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
{
    redirectUrl = @"https://localhost:44301/en/Account/ExternalLoginCallback?ReturnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44301%2Fen%2Flogin%3FAccountTypeId%3D0%26OrganisationRegister%3DFalse";
    var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(model.Provider, redirectUrl);
    return Challenge(properties, model.Provider);
}
```

The idea here is that a user is sent to ExternalLoginCallback, which creates their account locally, then sent back to the login page for authentication. Obviously I wouldn't normally hard-code the redirect, I'm just trying to get things working.

In my application, the following URLs are both set as valid "redirect URLs" in Azure:

https://localhost:44301/en/Account/ExternalLoginCallback
https://localhost:44301/en/login

And these should match the values being passed in to the Challenge - so I'm really confused as to what Azure is complaining about here? What settings do I need to join this up?

In case this was a local development issue I have tried deploying the application to a test server running under our domain, and adding those URLs to Azure too, but it gets the same result.

Comment: Can you find detailed error message which shows which redirect url is config ? And how do you config the authentication using AAD in .net Core ?

Comment: You can try to delete the `redirectUrl =`statement  , and register `https://localhost:xxx/signin-oidc`  as reply url in AD portal .